# Trouble removing null fields and delimiter while concatenating in access select query

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation, microsoft-access-2013

I am relatively brand new to Access (using 2013). I'm linking my query to Excel which is working fine.

I had a `concat` function that I probably got from this site but Excel didn't like linking with an undefined function so I can't use any of those in my solution (at least I think so). Anyway, I am trying to concatenate all but one of my fields in a select query into a column with a period `.` delimiter with the option to not show the period or field if the field is null.

I have used `Iif` statements like this in the expression builder below but still have random periods even when the field(s) in question are blank.

```
NewColumnName: Iif(IsNull([field1],"",[field1]&". ") & Iif(IsNull([field2]),"", [field2]&". ")
```

And so on and so forth for about seven total fields. Any ideas on how to properly concatenate all fields with a period while skipping null fields to remove any leading or trailing periods?

(Side note: I viewed a Youtube video where they used a `+` symbol as opposed to an ampersand and that worked in a test database but I can't replicate that in my real one. It was ideal because it didn't have the long `Iif` but I will do whatever is necessary at this point. That line was like:

```
NewColumnName: [Field1] & (" "+[field2]+". " & (" "+[field3]+". ")
```

Comment: You have capitalized `[Field1]` was this intentional or just a typo?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. Some of the blank cells in my tables were not reading as Null. I utilized an Update query to change the blank cells to Null. The "update" was "Null" and the "criteria" was ="".

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.